# Good example to explain REST is completely independent of HTTP and the Web

Tags: web-services, http, rest, rpc

The other day I was explaining my friend that REST is an architecture style that relies on a stateless, client-server, cacheable communications protocol. One of the points was trying to make was the fact that REST has nothing to do with HTTP (even if, virtually in all cases, the HTTP protocol is used for designing networked applications). However, I couldn't come up with single real world example that implement REST using other protocol or RPC mechanism.

Does anyone know a real world system that implements REST on communication mechanism other than HTTP?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one called [Constrained Application Protocol (CoAP)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-core-coap/).  Obscure, no doubt.

Comment: The CoAP draft is just the application layer UDP packet format protocol, for less obscure information see [draft-shelby-core-interfaces](http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-shelby-core-interfaces-01.html)

Answer (score 1):

[1060 Research's Netkernel](http://www.1060research.com/netkernel/) implements an architectural model they call **Resource Oriented Computing** (ROC) which is a generalization of the principles underlying REST (state is represented in immutable entities exchanged between actors).  It is targeted mostly at HTTP, but their ROC concept works independently of it.

Answer (score 1):

**AtomPub** - the *The Atom Publishing Protocol* - is based on REST principles as well. See [the specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5023.txt).